# TypeScript system modules not registering imported file locations

Tags: typescript, systemjs, typescript1.6

#### Problem

I'm using TypeScript v. 1.6.2 to compile my ts sources into js using ES5 and `system` modules. My expectation is for the JS to have a `system.register` populated with an array of strings that represent the imported source locations. For example:

```
System.register(['angular2/angular2', 'angular2/router', 'angular2/http'], 
    function(exports_1) { ...
```

However, in my case, `system.register` is *empty*. I'm not sure why it is empty, but I clearly cannot proceed without any imports. Below is a sketch of my file structure, example source code, and my `tsconfig.json`.

**File Structure**

```
  |index.js
  |
  |components
     |
     |--Bike
        |
        -Bike.ts
```

**Source**

```
/// <reference path="components/Bike/Bike.ts" />

import { Bike } from 'components/Bike/Bike';

export class TestClass {
    
    public bike: Bike;
    
    constructor(bike: Bike) {
        
        this.bike = bike;

        console.log('Bike new TestClass');
        
    }
        
}

...

export class Bike {

    constructor() {
    
        console.log('new bike');
        
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
/// <reference path="components/Bike/Bike.ts" />

  //NOTICE - no locations in the registry!

System.register([], function(exports_1) {
    var TestClass;
    return {
        setters:[],
        execute: function() {
            TestClass = (function () {
                function TestClass(bike) {
                    this.bike = bike;
                    console.log('Bike new TestClass');
                }
                return TestClass;
            })();
            exports_1("TestClass", TestClass);
        }
    }
});
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "system",
        "declaration": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "listFiles": true,
        "outDir": "target/js"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "jspm_packages",
        "bower_components",
        "d3",
        "plottable",
        "angular2",
        "target"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the same issue. The problem is, that you're using the type `Bike` only for declaration. You don't call anything on the class `Bike` (a static function for example) or passing `Bike` as a parameter or the like. Therefore there is no need for importing `Bike` in the compiled javascript file (at least from the compilers point of view or the typescript-team, who created the compiler)

But I found a solution for that: The compiler option `emitDecoratorMetadata:true` ensures that also `Bike` will be imported. Here the description from https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Compiler-Options:

> Emit design-type metadata for decorated declarations in source. See [issue #2577](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2577) for details.

I hope this helps.

Comment: That's a decent diagnosis, except that my tsconfig *does* set `emitDecoratorMetadata: true`. Something odd was happening when I wrote this. I'm not having this issue currently. Answer accepted because it's probably the issue most who hit this page are looking for.

Answer (score -2):

> in my case, system.register is empty. I'm not sure why it is empty,

You *only get what you `import`*.

E.g. to get `angular2/angular2` as a dependency you need something like:

```
import * as angular2 from "angular2/angular2";
```

Comment: In my example I am importing the module `Bike`. Surely this should cause my registry to have `['components/Bike/Bike']` right?